# Tomcat server restart history in Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

I am running a tomcat application in Linux. The server is getting restarted multiple times. I am able to get the last restart time.

But I want to knnow how many times the server got restarted in a day. Do we have a command to get this detail?

Comment: What is causing the restarts?  Tomcat has a log that should show something like `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.26]`.  You could find the logs and grep for that.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it from the logs